# Compute proportion of values by factor

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this (18,000 rows). Each row has a p-value and a "frequency" attached. Frequency is a factor that goes from 0 until 31.

```
 > head(df)
                  Gene P.value Frequency
    3  ENSG00000000419  1.000         1
    9  ENSG00000001084  0.851         2
    12 ENSG00000001461  0.699         4
    26 ENSG00000002746  0.113        23
    28 ENSG00000002834  0.529        12
    33 ENSG00000003137  0.464        31
```

How do I create a new dataframe that count the proportion of P.values, at each Frequency, that is less than say, 0.01?

I want the result to look like this:

```
> head(result_Df)

Frequency   Proportion
        0         0.02
        1         0.3
        2         0.02
        3         0.15
```

I think dplyr does this fairly quickly, but I'm not experienced in that package. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `dplyr`. Assign 1 to cases where P.value < 0.01, sum the ones and divide by total number of rows, per group.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Frequency) %>%
  summarise(Proportion = sum(ifelse(P.value < 0.01, 1, 0)) / n())
```

Example data and result:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Frequency = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                  P.value = c(0.001, 0.1, 0.2, 0.007, 0.009, 0.01))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Frequency Proportion
      <dbl>      <dbl>
1         1      0.333
2         2      0.667
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(result_Df)
result_Df[ , .(Proportion = sum( P.value < .01 ) / .N ) , by=Frequency ]
```

Note there is doing things quickly, and then there is doing things with as few code lines as possible.

Both things have merit, and there is definitely a culture for the latter in code based on dplyr.

data.table has been written to be quick though, which might be preferable in this case. (it's surely quite short too)

Comparing dplyr and data.table for 18k synthetic rows it looks like this:

```r
lirary(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(100)
n <- 18e3
synthetic_Df = data.frame(
    Gene = sprintf( "ENSG%011d", ceiling(runif( n, min=1, max=2e4 )) ),
    P.value = runif( n ),
    Frequency = ceiling( runif( n, min=1, max=30 ) )
)

dt <- as.data.table(synthetic_Df)

microbenchmark(
    dplyr = synthetic_Df %>% group_by( Frequency ) %>% summarize( Proporion = sum( P.value < .01 ) / n() ),
    data.table = dt[ , .(Proportion = sum( P.value < .01 ) / .N) , by=Frequency ]
)
```

Output:

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
      dplyr 2004.720 2052.8060 2123.1076 2070.6640 2106.617 4793.772   100   b
 data.table  833.253  856.5115  915.5324  876.6245  904.607 3659.965   100  a
```

A good 2.5 times faster with data.table. That doesn't mean the dplyr approach isn't good enough in this case, it most likely is.